# How to keep contentOffset to zero?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I have a problem. The contentOffset of my `UITableView` becomes (0, -64). It seems to me it happens in order to put content below `UINavigationBar`. But it is transparent in my app. What should I do to prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your table view controller:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```